# Convert strings in a list to raw string for re.search

Tags: python, regex

I need to check file extension when search over a directory.

if using re to do the matching work. those '.' is interpreted as regex '.'

my code:

```
extension = ['.c','.h']
path = 'foo\bar\foobar.c'

def skipCheck(path):
    global extension 
    skip = True
    for i in extension :
        if(re.search(i,path)):
            skip = False
return skip
```

I know I could use backslash to do this.

```
extension = ['\.c','\.h']
```

But it is not easy to use and configure.I want to keep the ['.c','.h'] input style.

Is there a way to convert and save them to another list of raw string for re.search.

Comment: "Raw string" means a literal of the form `r"foo"`. What you have are just, well, strings.

Comment: The regexes you're proposing will also catch files like 'spam.ham.eggs' and '.config'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use regexen; Python already has [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

   ```
   def skip_check(path):
       return os.path.splitext(path)[1] in extensions
   ```

   If you *really must* use a regex, you can call [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape all regex metacharacters.
2. Don't declare `extension` global; you're not assigning to it so you don't need to. Also, you should call it `extensions`.

Comment: This will have difficulties if one of the extensions has multiple separators (".tar.gz"), which is a use case I often encounter.

Comment: @DSM: true -- but then there isn't a well-defined behaviour for multiple extensions. `.tar.gz` is common, but `.dvi.pdf` isn't. (Note that `.tar.gz` is in fact a tarfile that's been gzipped. It actually is two extensions.)

Comment: The syntactic number of extensions [given some set to draw from] doesn't always correspond to the semantic number, so I've often needed to branch on something like filename.endswith((".tar.gz", ".tgz")) even though ".tar.gz" has two extensions and ".tgz" has one.  +1 anyway, it's simply annoying that the right thing to do doesn't work so nicely in a common case.